# trying to parse a linktext in c#

Tags: c#

How to parse a link as example: 'a/b/c' ?

How could I fix this code that returns: 1. 'a' 2. 'b/c' 3. empty

```
int getSizeOfParser(string links, char c)
    {
        int size = 0;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(links))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < links.Length; i++)
            {
                if (links[i] == c)
                    size++;
            }
            return size + 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    string[] parsedLink(string links, char c)
    {
        int size = getSizeOfParser(links, c);
        if (size == -1)
            return null;

        string[] parsed = new string[size];
        int i = 0, index = 0, tmp = 0;
        while (i < links.Length)
        {
            if (links[i] == c)
            {
                parsed[index++] = links.Substring(tmp, i++);
                tmp = i;
            }
            else
                i++;
        }
        return parsed;
    }
```

Comment: Use [Split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2), the second argument of `SubString` is its length from the index int he first argument:

> Substring(Int32, Int32)
>   Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position and has a specified length.

So what you want to do is:

```
if (links[i] == c)
        {
            parsed[index++] = links.Substring(tmp, i-tmp);
            tmp = i+1;
        }
i++;
```

instead of:

```
if (links[i] == c)
        {
            parsed[index++] = links.Substring(tmp, i++);
            tmp = i;
        }
        else
            i++;
```